# HIVE 0.12.0 installaion in hadoop 2.2.0

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am new to Hadoop ,i installed Hadoop 2.2.0 in Pseudo mode and want to install **Hive 0.12.0  version** or any other version that is compatible to hadoop 2.2.0 to Practice can anyone please tell the proper steps to install Hive .Thanks in Advance.

Note :

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 version .

Comment: Have you tried the steps mentioned in Apache Hadoop? If so, what error are you getting? If not, Please try and let us know where you are struck

Answer (score 1):

Since you have hadoop already installed, Hive installation is as easy as untaring the hive tarball on your machine. Download hive 12 from http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hive/ 
Then just modify your path in .bash_profile adding the location where you installed hive. The only tricky part is setting up the Hive megastore which by default is derby but you can change that to MYSQL or other RDMBS, more info here: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_18_4.html

Comment: That link no contains version 0.12, for version 0.12 you have to go to https://archive.apache.org/dist/hive/hive-0.12.0/